# Grover with 3 qubits

Tags: grovers-algorithm

Could someone please post a screenshot or a link for Grover's algorithm with 3 qubits with an oracle tuned for the solution at 101 ?

Comment: I am confused that after 2 iterations you have all states painted in red, which means, their amplitudes are negative. Or what means red ?

Answer (score 1):

In ["Complete 3-Qubit Grover Search on a Programmable Quantum Computer"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10535)
by Figgatt et. la., you will find all Boolean and phase oracles for the single-solution Grover search algorithm in *table I*.

Comment: This is really nice article, thanks for that. +1